# What is a good strategy for grouping reference types into a single value?

Tags: rust

I have a signature that looks like this (it isn't necessary to specify the lifetime parameter `'a`):

```rust
fn equip_slot<'a, I: Join>(
    log: &'a mut WriteExpect<GameLog>,
    entities: &'a Read<EntitiesRes>,
    backpack: &'a mut WriteStorage<InBackpack>,
    items: I,
    equipped_items: &'a mut WriteStorage<Equipped>,
    names: &'a ReadStorage<Name>,
    new_equip: Equipped,
    new_equip_ent: Entity,
) -> HashSet<(Entity, Item)>
where
    I: Copy,
    I::Type: IsItem,
```

`cargo clippy` rightly points out that this function has too many parameters. I was trying a few approaches to group these parameters into a tuple, but the act of creating a tuple (even of references) seems to cause some difficulties.

For instance:

```rust
type EquipData<'a, I> = (
    &'a Read<'a, EntitiesRes>,
    &'a mut WriteExpect<'a, GameLog>,
    &'a mut WriteStorage<'a, InBackpack>,
    I,
    &'a mut WriteStorage<'a, Equipped>,
    &'a ReadStorage<'a, Name>,
);

// ...

fn equip_slot<'a, I: Join + Copy>(
    equip_data: EquipData<'a, I>,
    new_equip: Equipped,
    new_equip_ent: Entity,
) -> HashSet<(Entity, Item)>
where
    I::Type: IsItem,

// Then at the call site, the following original line:
equip_slot(&mut log, &entities, &mut backpack, &items, &mut equipped, &names, new_equip, useitem.item);
// is changed to
equip_slot((&entities, &mut log, &mut backpack, &items, &mut equipped, &names), new_equip, useitem.item);
```

But now I get many errors, related to lifetimes in particular. Is there a better way to try to deal with this, or am I doing something wrong with the current approach? Here are the errors:

```
error[E0521]: borrowed data escapes outside of closure
   --> src/inventory_system.rs:180:25
    |
117 |             mut log,
    |             ------- `log` declared here, outside of the closure body
...
180 |                         equip_slot((&entities, &mut log, &mut backpack, &items, &mut equipped, &names), new_equip, useitem.item);
    |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: lifetime may not live long enough
   --> src/inventory_system.rs:177:53
    |
128 |               mut equipped,
    |               ------------ lifetime `'2` appears in the type of `equipped`
...
148 |               .for_each(|(player_entity, _player, useitem, player_name)| {
    |                         ------------------------------------------------ lifetime `'1` represents this closure's body
...
177 |                       targets.first().iter().for_each(|target| {
    |  _____________________________________________________^
178 | |                         let new_equip = Equipped::new(**target, &player_equip, &equip.allowed_slots);
179 | |                         // TODO: warn on non-unit discard?:
180 | |                         equip_slot((&entities, &mut log, &mut backpack, &items, &mut equipped, &names), new_equip, useitem.item);
181 | |                      });
    | |______________________^ closure capture requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
    |
    = note: closure implements `FnMut`, so references to captured variables can't escape the closure

error[E0499]: cannot borrow `log` as mutable more than once at a time
   --> src/inventory_system.rs:187:49
    |
128 |             mut equipped,
    |             ------------ lifetime `'2` appears in the type of `equipped`
...
177 |                     targets.first().iter().for_each(|target| {
    |                                                     -------- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
180 |                         equip_slot((&entities, &mut log, &mut backpack, &items, &mut equipped, &names), new_equip, useitem.item);
    |                         --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                         |                           |
    |                         |                           first borrow occurs due to use of `log` in closure
    |                         argument requires that `log` is borrowed for `'2`
...
187 |                         targets.iter().for_each(|target| {
    |                                                 ^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
...
194 |                                 log.entries.push(format!(
    |                                 --- second borrow occurs due to use of `log` in closure

error[E0499]: cannot borrow `log` as mutable more than once at a time
   --> src/inventory_system.rs:220:29
    |
128 |             mut equipped,
    |             ------------ lifetime `'2` appears in the type of `equipped`
...
177 |                     targets.first().iter().for_each(|target| {
    |                                                     -------- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
180 |                         equip_slot((&entities, &mut log, &mut backpack, &items, &mut equipped, &names), new_equip, useitem.item);
    |                         --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                         |                           |
    |                         |                           first borrow occurs due to use of `log` in closure
    |                         argument requires that `log` is borrowed for `'2`
...
220 |                             log.entries.push(format!(
    |                             ^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here

error[E0499]: cannot borrow `log` as mutable more than once at a time
   --> src/inventory_system.rs:234:34
    |
128 |             mut equipped,
    |             ------------ lifetime `'2` appears in the type of `equipped`
...
177 |                     targets.first().iter().for_each(|target| {
    |                                                     -------- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
180 |                         equip_slot((&entities, &mut log, &mut backpack, &items, &mut equipped, &names), new_equip, useitem.item);
    |                         --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                         |                           |
    |                         |                           first borrow occurs due to use of `log` in closure
    |                         argument requires that `log` is borrowed for `'2`
...
234 |                             .map(|victim| {
    |                                  ^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
...
245 |                                     log.entries.push(format!(
    |                                     --- second borrow occurs due to use of `log` in closure

error[E0597]: `log` does not live long enough
   --> src/inventory_system.rs:180:53
    |
148 |             .for_each(|(player_entity, _player, useitem, player_name)| {
    |                       ------------------------------------------------ value captured here
...
180 |                         equip_slot((&entities, &mut log, &mut backpack, &items, &mut equipped, &names), new_equip, useitem.item);
    |                                                     ^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
259 |     }
    |     -
    |     |
    |     `log` dropped here while still borrowed
    |     borrow might be used here, when `log` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `specs::Write<'_, GameLog, PanicHandler>`

error[E0597]: `backpack` does not live long enough
   --> src/inventory_system.rs:180:63
    |
148 |             .for_each(|(player_entity, _player, useitem, player_name)| {
    |                       ------------------------------------------------ value captured here
...
180 |                         equip_slot((&entities, &mut log, &mut backpack, &items, &mut equipped, &names), new_equip, useitem.item);
    |                                                               ^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
259 |     }
    |     -
    |     |
    |     `backpack` dropped here while still borrowed
    |     borrow might be used here, when `equipped` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `Storage<'_, components::Equipped, FetchMut<'_, MaskedStorage<components::Equipped>>>`
    |
    = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are defined

error[E0597]: `equipped` does not live long enough
   --> src/inventory_system.rs:180:86
    |
148 |             .for_each(|(player_entity, _player, useitem, player_name)| {
    |                       ------------------------------------------------ value captured here
...
180 |                         equip_slot((&entities, &mut log, &mut backpack, &items, &mut equipped, &names), new_equip, useitem.item);
    |                                                                                      ^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
259 |     }
    |     -
    |     |
    |     `equipped` dropped here while still borrowed
    |     borrow might be used here, when `equipped` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `Storage<'_, components::Equipped, FetchMut<'_, MaskedStorage<components::Equipped>>>`

error[E0597]: `names` does not live long enough
   --> src/inventory_system.rs:180:97
    |
148 |             .for_each(|(player_entity, _player, useitem, player_name)| {
    |                       ------------------------------------------------ value captured here
...
180 |                         equip_slot((&entities, &mut log, &mut backpack, &items, &mut equipped, &names), new_equip, useitem.item);
    |                                                                                                 ^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
259 |     }
    |     -
    |     |
    |     `names` dropped here while still borrowed
    |     borrow might be used here, when `log` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `specs::Write<'_, GameLog, PanicHandler>`
    |
    = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are defined

error[E0382]: use of partially moved value: `equip_data`
   --> src/inventory_system.rs:347:21
    |
270 |     let (entities, log, backpack, items, equipped_items, names) = equip_data;
    |                                          -------------- value partially moved here
...
347 |                     equip_data,
    |                     ^^^^^^^^^^ value used here after partial move
    |
    = note: partial move occurs because `equip_data.4` has type `&mut Storage<'_, components::Equipped, FetchMut<'_, MaskedStorage<components::Equipped>>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Comment: I don't think that creating a tuple solves the problem of having too many arguments, it just obfuscates the call.

Comment: It is difficult to say without understanding what the function does. My hunch though is that the function does more than it should and would benefit from being refactored into several separate steps.

Comment: The canonical approach to having too many (unnamed) function arguments is to make a struct to hold them. That said, if you're having lifetime problems then that won't help.

Comment: A rule of thumb: for each different lifetime give a new lifetime parameter. Now, you can reduce the number of parameters, but first do it correctly then do it short.

Comment: If you want the shortest version possible, then for all places where the lifetime is directly under the reference (`&'a T` or `&'a mut T`) you can use the same lifetime. About the other cases, for the places not behind a mutable reference but behind a shared one you _may_ be able to use the same lifetime, I cannot tell. For the rest use a different lifetime for each.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I ascribed 5 different lifetime parameters (one for each tuple member that is a reference), like `&'a Read<'a, EntitiesRes>, &'b mut WriteExpect<'b, GameLog>`, but had the same issue. I then decoupled the lifetimes further by using 10 different life time parameters, like `&'a Read<'a1, EntitiesRes>,  &'b mut WriteExpect<'b1, GameLog>`, and it worked! Thanks for the tip, I'll have to study this a bit more to understand why.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments - based on your feedback and revisiting the output from the compiler, I've attempted to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Using the comments to my question (in particular, the suggestion to use a different lifetime parameter everywhere possible), I was able to come up with a solution.

Note that before I extracted some of the parameters into a tuple, lifetime parameters were inferred for the `equip_slot` function. In particular, the lifetime parameters for the internal storage values were not specified (I only -- optionally -- specified the lifetime parameters for the references to the Storage structures). But when we declare a type, we must specify the lifetime parameters:

```rust
type EquipData<'a, 'b, I> = (
    &'a Read<'b, EntitiesRes>,
    &'a mut WriteExpect<'b, GameLog>,
    &'a mut WriteStorage<'b, InBackpack>,
    I,
    &'a mut WriteStorage<'b, Equipped>,
    &'a ReadStorage<'b, Name>,
);
```

This shows that the internal storage values must have a different lifetime parameter (`'b`) from the references to storage themselves (`'a`). In particular, for the mutable references, we must have e.g.  `&'a mut WriteExpect<'b, GameLog>` not  `&'a mut WriteExpect<'a, GameLog>`. If we don't, then we get several errors, but in particular:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
   --> src/inventory_system.rs:160:53
    |
100 |               mut log,
    |               ------- lifetime `'2` appears in the type of `log`
...
131 |               .for_each(|(player_entity, _player, useitem, player_name)| {
    |                         ------------------------------------------------ lifetime `'1` represents this closure's body
...
160 |                       targets.first().iter().for_each(|target| {
    |  _____________________________________________________^
161 | |                         let new_equip = Equipped::new(**target, &player_equip, &equip.allowed_slots);
162 | |                         // TODO: warn on non-unit discard?:
163 | |                         equip_slot((&entities, &mut log, &mut backpack, &items, &mut equipped, &names), new_equip, useitem.item);
164 | |                      });
    | |______________________^ closure capture requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
    |
    = note: closure implements `FnMut`, so references to captured variables can't escape the closure
```

and

```
error[E0597]: `log` does not live long enough
   --> src/inventory_system.rs:163:53
    |
131 |             .for_each(|(player_entity, _player, useitem, player_name)| {
    |                       ------------------------------------------------ value captured here
...
163 |                         equip_slot((&entities, &mut log, &mut backpack, &items, &mut equipped, &names), new_equip, useitem.item);
    |                                                     ^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
242 |     }
    |     -
    |     |
    |     `log` dropped here while still borrowed
    |     borrow might be used here, when `log` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `specs::Write<'_, GameLog, PanicHandler>`
```

Our reference value (e.g. `log`) may be dropped, but we still need to be sure that the Storage values themselves outlive the reference `log`, since it was captured via closure (and potentially used outside the closure). Thus we need to decouple via separate lifetime parameters `'a` and `'b`. In our case, that is all the resolution we need.

And now, we can go back to `equip_slot` automatically inferring the lifetime parameters:

```rust
fn equip_slot<I: Join + Copy>(
    equip_data: EquipData<I>,
    new_equip: Equipped,
    new_equip_ent: Entity,
) -> HashSet<(Entity, Item)>
where
    I::Type: IsItem,
```